# How to efficiently calculate which region a polygon is in relation to a polynomial with a pencil-and-paper procedure?

Tags: polynomials, polygons, computational-geometry

A polynomial splits $\mathbb{R}^2$ into 3 regions: above, below, and where the polynomial lies.

A polygon is made up of line segments.  The polygon's spatial relationship to a polynomial can be one of 5 possibilities:

1. Completely above
2. Completely below
3. Completely above and on.
4. Completely below and on.
5. The polynomial runs through the polygon, so all three.

Here are some photos of a polygon and a polynomial segment:

[image: A random polygon completely above a polynomial except possibly 1 point.] [image: A different random polygon completely above a different polynomial except possibly 1 point.]

Where 'and' mean some points are one and the other points are the other(s).
So, given a polynomial how do we know if
either always be above the polynomial without intersection.

I think there should be a way to do this without requiring numerically solving when each line segment intersects (or doesn't) using a complicated polynomial equation. Kind of how we can use the cross product of vectors to see if they intersect, but are generalized? Convolutions? I am not sure how to approach this.

**UPDATE:**
Solving a polynomial of high order or with many terms is not a satisfactory solution. I believe that there should be a way to do this without having to invert a polynomial or at least not such a complicated polynomial as the starting polynomial. Maybe some matrix using the given information, and then based on the form of the matrix, having the solution.

Comment: It sounds like you already know how to solve it (by intersecting each line segment with the polynomial), so I'm not sure what more there is to say, or what your question is.  It's also not clear why you think there should be a better method, or what would be the metric by which some other approach would be "better".

Comment: @D.W. I'm guessing this is for a computational application, so a different test would be "better" if it involved fewer steps, and ideally, did not involve inverting a polynomial.

Comment: If you are asking for a more efficient algorithm, please [edit] your question to ask for that.  Be explicit.  If you are asking for a pencil-and-paper procedure you can use without a computer, please ask for that.  Please don't make us guess what you are asking.

Comment: @a52 Yes, a different test would be "better" if it involved fewer steps, and ideally did not involve inverting a polynomial. I know that we can do this with two lines, and in essence the question is if we can do something analogous with a known line segment and a known polynomial.

Comment: @D.W. I am asking for a pencil-and-paper procedure that I can use without a computer and will edit it. If the polynomial is order 35 or some other ridiculously complex polynomial, solving it by hand is not practical.

Comment: You say you don't want to have to invert the polynomial, but what about evaluating the polynomial? If you evaluate the polynomial at n-points (i.e. at the x-value coordinates of your polygon corners) you should have a simple way of finding true-positives when crossings or on-the-line points do occur - then you just have to flesh out an algorithm (possibly slower or more complicated) that can find false-negatives (where line crossings occur despite all polygon corners being on the same side of the function).

Comment: @AmateurDotCounter Evaluating polynomials is of course okay. I think you are describing my intuition.  I am going to play around with it in my free time this week.

Comment: My question is somewhat a duplicate of this question from this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742382/segment-polygon-intersection). But for a polynomial segment instead of a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your polynomial has degree $d$, I doubt you can avoid having to do root-finding on a polynomial of degree $d$.

Indeed, suppose there was a better method to solve your problem.  Then, intuitively speaking, it seems likely we could use it for root-finding, too.  Given a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ where we want to check whether it has any real roots, we'd form a region of space given by $y\ge 0$, and check the relationship between $p(x)$ and this region of space; the result (which of those 5 categories) tells us whether $p(x)$ has a root or not.  You can also use it to check whether $p(x)$ has a root in some interval $x \in [\ell,u]$, by forming the region defined by $y \ge 0, x \ge \ell, x \le u$.

This is not a fully rigorous argument, because it involves an open region of space, and a polygon is closed.  But it's not obvious to me how an algorithm could usefully take advantage of the closed nature of polygons to make the problem much simpler.  So treat this as a 'plausibility argument' that maybe we shouldn't expect better methods for this problem.